# How to return an observable from http request

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following request in a `service` in angular 9 :

```
getUsers(value: string, offset = 0) {
    return this.http.get<GetUsers>(`users`);
  }
```

This allow me to subscribe and fetch the result in the `component`, but my `service` can't fetch the data.

I would like that this function will execute the request, read the response and then return the observable to the `component`

I tried

```
  return this.http.get<GetUsers>(`users`)
      .map(res => { 
            //do my stuff
            return res;
      });
```

but I have >Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable

I tried using

```
.pipe(
      map(res => {
        console.log(res)
        return res;
      })
    );
```

but it say there is no `map` did you mean `Map` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the overservable correctly. The reason why you're getting the error for map is probably because you don't have `rxjs` installed

Try this:

1. `npm install rxjs --save`
2. Add `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` to your file

Comment: it s included in angular, and it s in the package. but you might be right  I try the npm i again

Comment: You might just need the `import` statement then. Most IDE's should detect the import automatically but not sure which one you are using.

Comment: Yes, the import was missing. Thank you

Comment: you need to wait 10 min to mark answer, now it s ok

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check your package.json if 'rxjs' package exists. If not, install it by entering following command on terminal.

```
npm install rxjs --save
```

You just have to import the "map" operator from "rxjs" that comes pre-installed in angular.
Just add this line on top of your component file based on Angular version.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

or

```
import { map } from 'rxjs';
```

Now it should work fine.